# Interview Question: Insert switch to maximize time lightbulb spends on

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here is the problem statement:

> You have a lightbulb for an interval of N seconds, where N is given.
>   At time 0, the lightbulb switches on, and at time N, it switches off,
>   regardless of any switches. From time 1 to time N-1 you have a maximum
>   of N-2 switches in the form of an array called switches, which turn
>   the lightbulb to the opposite of what it currently is i.e. if it's on
>   it'll turn off and vice versa. For example suppose N = 8 and switches
>   = [1,2]. The lightbulb will switch on at time 0, a switch at time 1 will turn it off, a switch at time 2 will turn it on, and it'll remain
>   on until time 8, when it turns off. Hence, the time it remains on is
>   equal to 1-0 + 8-2 = 7.
>
> Now suppose you have to insert a switch in this interval, where there
>   is not already a switch present. What is the maximum time the
>   lightbulb remains on once you insert the switch. For example, in the
>   above case, the solution would be 6 since inserting a switch at time 7
>   keeps the time the lightbulb spends on maximum. Since 1-0 + 7-2 = 6,
>   the answer is 6.

I solved the problem using a brute force solution, using the reasoning that  if you insert a switch at time k, the states of the lightbulb before this wouldn't be affected, and the states of the lightbulb from time k to time N will be reversed, and hence you can find the time it spends on after time k by (N - k) - t, where t is the time it would spend on from time k to N without the inserted switch. Hence, I can calculate the time the lightbulb would spend on for each time position of the inserted switch and maximize it. However, since calculating the time the lightbulb spends on is a O(n) operation and I go through all possible positions, my solution is O(n^2) and this caused my code to time out for some test cases.

Can someone propose a better solution?

Comment: Start at the last possible position for the switch and move to the front. Doing this, you can calculate the change for each new position incrementally in constant time since you only need to add one new interval.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53847955/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/101777/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  (I realize you're just responding to a suggestion from someone else in a comment, but I wanted to let you know for the future.)

Answer (score 0):

If we're inserting in a block previously turned on then, as in your example, we would want to insert it as close as possible to the end of that `on` period. And if we're inserting in a previously `off` block, we'd place it as close as possible to that period's start to maximise that block's new `on` time.

To calculate the utility of any one choice in `O(1)`, we could refer to staggered prefix sums, accumulated from the end of the array. (As Nico Schertler commented above, we could perform the whole calculation dynamically in a single traversal from the end with constant space - left as an exercise :)

For example, given N = 10 and switches = [3,6], we have:

```
   3-0, 6-3, 10-6
   on , off, on

(skip every other value)
    <- - - - - -
Reversed prefix sums 1:
   7  , (4),  4
Reversed prefix sums 2:
   (3) , 3  , (0)
```

As we traverse the input, trying each block, our choice wouldn't affect the left sum, as you suggested. We can get the sum for the right side from our prefixes:

```
block 0: since it's previously `on`
   we'd place it towards the end
   at 2, resulting in

   2-0 (reduced from 3-0) +
   (0 for 3-2 time units when it's off) +
   3 (prefix sum in the next block)
   = 5

block 1: since it's previously `off`
   we'd place it towards the start
   at 4, resulting in

   3 (accumulated) +
   6-4 for when it's now on +
   0 (prefix sum in the next block)
   = 5

block 2: since it's previously `on`
   we'd place it towards the end
   at 9, resulting in

   3 (accumulated) +
   9-6 (reduced from 10-6) +
   (0 for 10-9 time units when it's off) +
   = 6
```